# External Links Getting crawled in Tika - Java

Tags: java, apache-tika

I'm using tika parser in Java to extract contents from pdfs, word documents and PPTs, and i don't want tika parser to read the hyperlinks in the document, but by default configuration it is getting crawled and causing me issues.

How to configure tika parser not to index the external links in the file?

Comment: How are you using / configuring Apache Tika? Tika certainly won't fetch external resources by default!

Comment: Hello, I have written java code to read the files  using apache tika. Since I will get different format of files, I used AutoDetectParser. It is working fine except this scenario: if any ppt or word document has any links to excel in the local file system, tika is trying to get that too. If that particular excel is missing in local file system it throws errors and not crawling the actual content of that ppt or word document. My usecase is to crawl only the ppt and word document. So, how can I stop tika not to crawl the links?